# Flutter Scrolling Issue Assistance Needed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, scroll

I have a pretty complicated question (You can find a reference in the dashboard section of MyFitnessPal). I have this image:
[image: My App]

If you look at the top left, you see a big yellow half ball type thing. Keep this in mind for the future.

**My Question**

EDIT: The footer should not move when the user is scrolling

I want this page to be

1. Scrollable
2. When the page is scrolling, I want the yellow circle to gradually get smaller and go away (slide to the top left corner). In addition, I want the JustLift (and the description), to slide up and away as soon as the user scrolls past a certain point. Finally, I want the Go premium button to slide up and to the left, so the profile image and the go premium button are next to each other. It should look something like this:

**PROFILE ____ Go Premium Btn _______________**

**ALL THE CARDS AT THE BOTTOM**

Terrible description but a brief idea of what I want
**If you would like a reference to see what I mean, you can go to the MyFitnessPal app and scroll down from the home page**

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Without a specific question or some better idea of what your problem is this just looks like a request for code.

Comment: I'm not asking for complete code, just an example or someone telling me the library to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a CustomScrollView together with a SliverAppBar, I made an example code below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff3b3838),
        centerTitle: false,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffff00)),
              child: const Text(
                'Go Premium!',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: 130,
        titleSpacing: 20,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
          background: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: -34,
                left: -40,
                child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(400),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        color: const Color(0xffffff00))),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 70,
                top: 50,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      'JustLift',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Without pain there is no gain',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xff9f9b9b)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Column(
            children: List.generate(200, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Item $index',
            ),
          );
        })),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Alright! I will try this in a sec!

Comment: one more thing. Do you know how to add a footer? That stays at the bottom? Is it just another SilverAppBar?

Comment: you can add a navbar inside the Scaffold

Comment: I have tried a lot to get the code to work with my pre-existing code, but can't figure it out. Would you mind making your code work with mine? I have no idea how to do it. Do you mind sharing a temporary email address so I can share a docs file with you? Thanks!

Comment: you can send it to this email: renatotest12345@gmail.com

Comment: alright perfect! I shared it with you. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me know if you need any more files or code!

Comment: From what I noticed your whole code is implemented inside a stack, you must implement the footer inside a bottomNavigationBar and not in the body of the Scaffold, I suggest you try to recreate it that way

Comment: return Scaffold(
         body:
     , bottomNavigationBar: < your footer >);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253015/discussion-between-promaster-and-renato-amaral).

Comment: Hey Renato can you check the chat for a sec? I have one last question regarding the flutter scrolling issue. Thanks!